# IIEXPRESS 8.0- Error: configuring iis express failed with the following error:Filename:redirection.config Error: cannot Read configuration file

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I had an issue today with a Network Drive where IISEXPRESS Directory is located

Disconnected from the Network Drive \ls2\jjhaidar$

Installed Visual Studio 2013

after installation is complete,  When creating a New Website from VS 2013, I am getting this error

configuring iis express failed with the following error:

Filename: redirection.config

Error: Cannot read configuration file.

as I understand, IIs Express is trying to look into  %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress  to  find the Filename: redirection.config

%IIS_USER_HOME% <-- %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\

%IIS_SITES_HOME% <-- %userprofile%\documents\my web sites

when  type form cmd prompt the following:

> echo %USERPROFILE%

it is showing me

C:\users\jjhaidar

and since IIEXPRESS is looking for  this director:%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress

I have created  "documents\iisexpress\" under  C:\users\jjhaidar

and copy the Config directory  under  C:\users\jjhaidar\documents\iisexpress

then copy these files :

applicationhost.config

```
redirection.config
```

under C:\users\jjhaidar\documents\iisexpress\config

then uninstall IIS Express and install it again.

But still getting the above error

```
 configuring iis express failed with the following error:

 Filename: redirection.config

 Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

Can someone tell  what directories  IIS express 8.0 is looking into to find this file:   redirection.config

is it  looking for a Network Drive?